# Mass import and shaping of data in R

Tags: r, readxl

SOF newbie here, so please bear with me and some daft questions!

Can anyone please tell me what the most efficient way would be to read in ~50+ excel files with multiple tabs into R, select a specific tab from all 50, and combine those tabs by date to create a large dataframe?

For example, let's assume I want to see what GP activity has been like in a specific healthcare region here in the UK for the last 4 years. I currently have to download many many monthly reports like this one [Appointments in General Practice, March 2022](https://files.digital.nhs.uk/68/DA267E/GP_APPT_Publication_March_2022_V2.xlsx)

I then have to go to table 3a, scroll down to the NHS area code "07k", and then paste the activity from that row into a separate excel sheet.

I have to do this a lot, and it takes hours, but am not coding literate enough to figure out a better way of doing this.

From the guidance of others, my attempts to date have involved downloading many months' data to a desktop folder. I set my working drive to that folder, and then attempt the following:

```
files <- list.files(pattern = "*.xls", full.names = TRUE)

for(i in files){
filepath <-    file.path("C:/Users/myname/Desktop/recordsfolder", i)
assign(i, readxl::read_xls(file path))
}
```

But the honest truth is I don't really understand this, nor what the next step would be.

If anyone could point me in a better direction I'd be very grateful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so there is a function `readData` that reads and filters each of the table 3a's from the files in `list.files`. You then apply this function to all of the files using `map` and then `bind_rows` to reduce the list of datasets to a single dataset.

I dont know how standardised your reports are so you may need to adjust the read function accordingly

```
library(readxl)
library(tidyverse)

readData <- function(path){
  colnames <- read_excel(path, sheet = "Table 3a", skip = 10, n_max = 1) %>% 
    gather(header1, header2) %>% 
    mutate(across(everything(), ~gsub("\\.\\.\\.\\d+", "", .))) %>% 
    mutate(colname = ifelse(header1=="", header2, paste0(header1, "_", header2))) %>% 
    pull(colname)
  read_excel(path, sheet = "Table 3a", skip = 13, col_names = colnames) %>% 
    filter(grepl("07k", `NHS Area Code`, ignore.case = TRUE))
  }

files <- list.files("C:/Users/myname/Desktop/recordsfolder", full.name = TRUE)

files %>% 
  map(readData) %>% 
  bind_rows()
```

Comment: Zimia, thank you so much for your answer. I've tried your code, which runs on my machine, but returns a nibble of 0 x 0. I know I sound like the beginner I am, but can I ask what about the code specifically I might need to change?

Following your narrative of the mythology used, there are bits of your code that I  don't understand. If you could explain very briefly how each component of the function works in a bit more detail I might be able to troubleshoot?

Thank you for your time, I appreciate it can be hard work guiding beginners.

Answer (score 0):

One approach is improve your workflow is to move away from excel files, whenever possible, especially if CSV files are already available.

For example, instead download the zip file `https://files.digital.nhs.uk/EA/072466/Appointments_GP_Daily_Mar_22.zip` and then read in the Mar 2022 csv, using `data.table::fread()`

```
library(data.table)
mar22 <- fread(cmd = 'unzip -p Appointments_GP_Daily_Mar_22.zip CCG_CSV_Mar_22.csv')
```

You can then construct information for Table 3a. For example, appointment counts by status and CCG:

```
dcast(
    mar22[, sum(COUNT_OF_APPOINTMENTS), .(CCG_NAME,APPT_STATUS,CCG_ONS_CODE)],
    CCG_ONS_CODE+CCG_NAME~APPT_STATUS, value.var="V1"
)
```

Output:

```
    CCG_ONS_CODE                                        CCG_NAME Attended   DNA Unknown
  1:    E38000006                                NHS Barnsley CCG   118066  5545    5595
  2:    E38000007                  NHS Basildon and Brentwood CCG   121998  3572    4626
  3:    E38000008                               NHS Bassetlaw CCG    61864  2293    1874
  4:    E38000014                   NHS Blackburn with Darwen CCG    76233  4228    3243
  5:    E38000015                               NHS Blackpool CCG    88336  5267    3362
 ---                                                                                    
102:    E38000253 NHS Hampshire Southampton and Isle of Wight CCG   763293 36026   30755
103:    E38000254                                NHS Kirklees CCG   219937  7859    7637
104:    E38000255                       NHS North East London CCG   865775 57636   42749
105:    E38000256                       NHS North West London CCG  1127325 59500   45858
106:    E38000257       NHS Shropshire and Telford and Wrekin CCG   236456  9836    9884
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help langtang. If I may, can I ask a question?

Does this mythology still leave the retirement to manually read in many different files, and merge them all by date manually? Apologies if I've misunderstood.